# creating a subroutine (VBscript)

Tags: vbscript, subroutine

This one should be extremely easy but I am new to VB script and for some reason I can't get a subroutine to work. I get the error " VBScript compilation error"
it points to line 5 `Sub add(a,b)`

```
Language="VBSCRIPT"
Sub CATmain()

add 5, 3
Sub add (a, b)
sum=a+b
msgbox sum
End Sub

End Sub
```

Sorry for the simple question. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Subroutine or a Function should be defined outside any other Subroutines and it should be called from main Subroutine when needed.

```
Function Add(A, B)
  Add = CInt(A) + CInt(B)
End Function
'Here Add should be a Function, not a Subroutine.

Sub CATmain()
Dim Sum
  Sum = Add(5, 3)
  'Calling Add and store its result in Sum Variable
  MsgBox "Sum: " + CStr(Sum)
End Sub

CATmain
'Calling your main Subroutine CATmain
```

[**`Sub`**](https://ss64.com/vb/sub.html) is used to declare the name, arguments, and code that form the body of a Sub procedure in VB Script.